# writing Latex code to dot file

Tags: graphs, dot2tex

is there a way to write Latex code to a dot file (in python with networkx for example) such that the latex code is then executed when read in a latex file?

If I create a dotfile with this code, and include it into latex using graphviz, the latex code is displayed as raw text and not executed.
Do I have to write the latex code in a special format?

```
import networkx as nx
def draw_graph():
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    G.add_edge(r'$\alpha$', r'$\beta$', label=r'$\alpha+\beta$')
    G.add_nodes_from([r'$\alpha$', r'$\beta$'])
    A = nx.drawing.nx_agraph.to_agraph(G)
    A.draw('somegraph.dot', prog='dot', args="-Grankdir=LR")
draw_graph()
```

I have also tried to convert the dot file to latex with dot2tex, but this transforms the latex code $\alpha$ to $alpha$ ...:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',line join=bevel,]
  \pgfsetlinewidth{1bp}
%%
\pgfsetcolor{black}
  % Edge: $\alpha$ -> $\beta$
  \draw [->] (77.003bp,18.0bp) .. controls (105.9bp,18.0bp) and (145.93bp,18.0bp)  .. (186.71bp,18.0bp);
  \definecolor{strokecol}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0};
  \pgfsetstrokecolor{strokecol}
  \draw (132.0bp,25.5bp) node {\$alpha+beta\$};
  % Node: $\alpha$
\begin{scope}
  \definecolor{strokecol}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0};
  \pgfsetstrokecolor{strokecol}
  \draw (38.5bp,18.0bp) ellipse (38.5bp and 18.0bp);
  \draw (38.5bp,18.0bp) node {\$alpha\$};
\end{scope}
  % Node: $\beta$
\begin{scope}
  \definecolor{strokecol}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0};
  \pgfsetstrokecolor{strokecol}
  \draw (221.5bp,18.0bp) ellipse (34.5bp and 18.0bp);
  \draw (221.5bp,18.0bp) node {\$beta\$};
\end{scope}
%
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You can use the `label` attribute when invoking `dot2tex` https://dot2tex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage_guide.html#labels

Comment: hmm but how can I add the labels in my python code?

Answer (score 2):

If it is just about using Greek letters as labels and no further LaTeX typesetting is needed (such as fractions etc.) then you can use Unicode input in your graph directly and save to a pdf, which can be included in your LaTeX document.

MWE:

```python
import networkx as nx
def draw_graph():
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    G.add_edge(r'α', r'β', label=r'α+β')
    G.add_nodes_from([r'α', r'β'])
    A = nx.drawing.nx_agraph.to_agraph(G)
    A.draw('somegraph2.pdf', prog='dot', args="-Grankdir=LR")
draw_graph()
```

Resulting pdf:

[image]

Comment: oh good to know, thanks! though I need to write equations in this case

Answer (score 1):

In your python script, remove the $ and escape the \

```
import networkx as nx
def draw_graph():
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    G.add_edge(r'\\alpha', r'\\beta', label=r'\\alpha+\\beta')
    G.add_nodes_from([r'\\alpha', r'\\beta'])
    A = nx.drawing.nx_agraph.to_agraph(G)
    A.draw('somegraph.dot', prog='dot', args="-Grankdir=LR")
draw_graph()
```

Running this script should give

```
strict digraph "" {
    graph [bb="0,0,224.89,36",
        rankdir=LR
    ];
    node [label="\N"];
    "\\alpha"    [height=0.5,
        pos="32.497,18",
        width=0.9027];
    "\\beta"     [height=0.5,
        pos="196.94,18",
        width=0.77632];
    "\\alpha" -> "\\beta"    [label="\\alpha+\\beta",
        lp="116.99,25.5",
        pos="e,168.77,18 65.38,18 92.225,18 130.2,18 158.46,18"];
}
```

Then invoke `dot2tex` with

```
dot2tex -t math --figonly -o somegraph.tex somegraph.dot
```

The `-t math` option is for embracing labels contents in math mode

And you get in `somegraph.tex`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,line join=bevel,]
  \pgfsetlinewidth{1bp}
%%
\pgfsetcolor{black}
  % Edge: \\alpha -> \\beta
  \draw [->] (65.394bp,18.0bp) .. controls (92.248bp,18.0bp) and (130.24bp,18.0bp)  .. (168.82bp,18.0bp);
  \definecolor{strokecol}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0};
  \pgfsetstrokecolor{strokecol}
  \draw (117.0bp,25.5bp) node {$\alpha+\beta$};
  % Node: \\beta
\begin{scope}
  \definecolor{strokecol}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0};
  \pgfsetstrokecolor{strokecol}
  \draw (197.0bp,18.0bp) ellipse (28.0bp and 18.0bp);
  \draw (197.0bp,18.0bp) node {$\beta$};
\end{scope}
  % Node: \\alpha
\begin{scope}
  \definecolor{strokecol}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0};
  \pgfsetstrokecolor{strokecol}
  \draw (32.5bp,18.0bp) node {$\alpha$};
\end{scope}
%
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: weird, with exactly the same dot code and the command 
`dot2tex -t math --figonly -o somegraph.tex somegraph.dot`
I get the latex code without the backslash:
```
...
\draw (117.0bp,25.5bp) node {$alpha+beta$};
...
\draw (197.0bp,18.0bp) node {$beta$}
```

Comment: I am using python 3.9 and dot2tex 2.11.3

Comment: I use python 3.7.3 and dot2tex 2.9.0